# Why can't I use ibrowse? -- Undefined function: :ibrowse.start/0

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to consume a JSON API with my first Elixir application, but I'm stuck very early on. I decided to use [HTTPotion](https://github.com/myfreeweb/httpotion) to manage the get requests, but when calling `HTTPotion.start` from the elixir shell, I get the following response:

```
{:error, {:ibrowse, {'no such file or directory', 'ibrowse.app'}}}
```

Curious, I decided to see if I could invoke ibrowse directly, but calling `:ibrowse.start` returns

```
** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: :ibrowse.start/0
:ibrowse.start()
```

I added HTTPotion to my `mix.exs`'s dependencies and ran `mix deps.get`, which completed successfully. Why can't HTTPotion and my IEx shell find ibrowse?

Comment: how did you start `iex`? is it possible you did not start it with `-S mix`?

Comment: I did start iex with `-S mix`. José and Eduardo located the problem below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTPotion depends on `ibrowse` which is a git dependency. Since Hex packages cannot contain git dependencies, you need to add it explicitly to your deps in `mix.exs` file:

```
{:ibrowse, github: "cmullaparthi/ibrowse", tag: "v4.1.0"}
```

Comment: HTTPotion's README got updated recently to address this confusion: https://github.com/myfreeweb/httpotion/commit/1419c64468483d192cc017f18de3412f9dca7fb4